# how to convert datetime to milliseconds in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I want to convert the datetime to millisecond my code is here

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
flyer = pd.read_csv("./csv/Flyers Dataset - Flyers Dataset.csv",parse_dates = ['timestamp'])

flyer.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)

flyer.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

so the flyer variable is basically my entire dataframe(it's my csv file). The csv 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLq2U.png

any sort of feedback will  be greatly appreciated. I am sorry about any of the formatting on this question this is only my second one.

Sincerely,

Gratefull StackOverflow User

Comment: What's your base reference date?

Comment: sorry i'm new to all of this can you explain what that is

Comment: Time in milliseconds wouldn't be a valid point of reference. E.g. how do I express 22 Feb 2019 12:00:00am in milliseconds? It wouldn't make sense. You need a base reference point i.e. 1 Jan 2019 12:00:00am and based on that, express the desired date in milliseconds, which is actually a timedelta object

Comment: oh ok so according to the csv my base reference date would be October 1 2018

Answer (score 0):

Given that the 'timestamp' column is a datetime object, and your base reference date is October 1 2018, here's how you can compute the timedelta in milliseconds

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
```

Firstly, get the timezone info from your sample timestamp input:

```
datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 13:56:36-0400', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
>>>datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 13, 56, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000)))
```

Then we can create a tz-aware base date with the same timezone details. You should be able to do the subtraction after that.

```
base_date = datetime(2018,10,1, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(-1,72000)))

flyer = pd.read_csv("./csv/Flyers Dataset - Flyers Dataset.csv",parse_dates = ['timestamp'])
flyer.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True)

# 1000 milliseconds in a second
flyer.loc[:,'TimeDelta'] = flyer.loc[:,'timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (x - base_date).total_seconds() * 1000)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)

flyer.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have no Timedelta in my csv nor a if there is any possible way you can just explain that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @aymanalmuti The ```parse_dates``` key in your read_csv should give you a datetime object for the timestamp column I think. Are you getting errors from the steps suggested above?

Comment: @aymanalmuti Sorry about that, I forgot to change the label of the column after testing it locally at my end! :D

Comment: is there a way to edit the timezone since I'm getting Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones error Thank you a bunch

Comment: Some steps will be required but what's the timezone of your timestamp column? Can you provide a sample exact value?

Comment: Yes the timezone is -4:00

Comment: Will you be able to paste the exact string for me? Just one of it will do

Comment: Do you mean like this 2018-10-01 13:56:36-04:00

Comment: @aymanalmuti A bit more troublesome with tz as I usually work with naive datetime.  You do not need to include ```datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 13:56:36-0400', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')``` in your script. I only put it there to show how I retrieved the timezone details to construct ```base_date = datetime(2018,10,1, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(-1,72000)))```

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for your help but i'm still getting an error hopefully this is just a simple fix but im getting datetime.datetime has no attribute timezone

Comment: How are you calling timezone? Please see my code above and use explicit imports to avoid confusion

Comment: Hey alright so I copied your whole code into mine and now i'm getting the same timezone error about Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones but the after error i got when I copied datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 13:56:36-0400', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z') into my python idle and got  datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 13, 56, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000))) so I copied tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000))) put it instead of yours

Comment: 1. ```from datetime import timezone``` 2. ```base_date = datetime(2018,10,1, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(-1,72000)))```. You shouldn't get anymore complaints about timezone attribute with these.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get home thank you for your time

Comment: Im running Python 3.7

Comment: @aymanalmuti I think I know what's wrong. Your dataframe is called _flyer_ and not _df_! I'll update my answer

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I already updated your answer before I ran the code from df to flyer but it still isn't working